# Realm query based on multiple ids

Tags: c#, realm, realm-mobile-platform

How can I query objects by multiple ids using realm database.
Entityframework allows something like this: `query.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id))`.
How is this possible with realm using c#?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a list containing all ids to be searched:

```
List<int> ids;
```

Then you could pass a function to `Where` clause:

```
Func<YourObject, bool> searchObject = o => ids.Contains(o.Id);
var result = realm.All<YourObject>().Where(searchObject);
```